# Spark MLLib exception LDA.class compiled against incompatible version

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

when I try to run a `Main` class with `sbt`, I get this error. What am I missing?

```
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'LDA.class'.
Could not access type Logging in package org.apache.spark,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'LDA.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.
```

My build.sbt looks like this:

```
"org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-core"       %   "2.0.1"      % Provided,
"org.apache.spark"          % "spark-mllib_2.11"  % "1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run the old sparkMllib on new Spark Core. i.e. your version of mllib and spark core are totally different.

Try using this:

```
"org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-core_2.11"       %   "2.0.1",
"org.apache.spark"          %% "spark-mllib_2.11"  % "2.0.1"
```

Thant might solve your problem !

Comment: now i get this: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.0.1: not found

Comment: @Darth.Vader:My Bad two % has to be there i have updated my answer use the code now